# Make keepalived send 0 priority when going to FAULT state

Tags: linux, high-availability, keepalived, vrrp

When stopping (service keepalived stop), keepalived does send the priority 0 adverts so the backup server takes over almost immediately. However, when it goes to fault mode (check script returns not zero) then it just shuts up and then the other server waits until the adverts time out (3x advert interval) before going to MASTER state.

Is there a way to make keepalived send priority 0 adverts when going to FAULT state? It would speed up the failover process as the other host would not need to wait until the adverts timed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up capturing the priority 0 packet and playing it back from the fault_notify script.